# Basic Authentication with Android HTTP POST

Tags: android

Does Basic HTTP Authentication work when attempting an HTTP POST via Android?

I've been working with some code that uses Basic Authentication when completing an HTTP GET request and it works perfectly.  I need to use the same authentication when completing an HTTP POST.

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(baseUrl+"events.json");
String credentials = email + ":" + password;
String base64EncodedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
request.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials);
request.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json");

try
{
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> vars = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    vars.add(new BasicNameValuePair("event[name]",currentEvent.name));
    vars.add(new BasicNameValuePair("event[location]",currentEvent.location));
    vars.add(new BasicNameValuePair("event[num_expected]",new Integer(currentEvent.num_expected).toString()));
    request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(vars));
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Log exception
    Log.e("CreateEvent", "doInBackground — " + Errors.getStackTrace(e));
}

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
try {
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");

        return 1;
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // Log exception
    Log.e("CreateEvent", "doInBackground — " + Errors.getStackTrace(e));
}
```

The response is an HTTP 500 error.  It's not returning any details, so I can't tell exactly what's wrong, but the only difference is the POST and the passing of form data.

Comment: I would guess the problem is not related to the Authorization header. Is that your server? Can you check the logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking your code with more detail it looks like you are setting the `Content-Type` to `application/json` but then sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data (I guess that's what `UrlEncodedFormEntity` does), thus the web service is failing to parse the data as a JSON.

Comment: Haha, it happens to all of us constantly ;-) Glad I could help.